# How should I correctly manage a full Core Data stack in private queue?

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, concurrency, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I handle two complete `Core Data` stacks in my app:

- The one that is provided by default in `AppDelegate`.
- A second stack I fully create in order to perform `NSManagedObject` updates in a private queue, to avoid blocking the UI.

I have a class to create the second "auxiliary" Core Data stack, and I do this way:

```
class CoreDataStack: NSObject {

   class func getPrivateContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {

       let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
       let modelURL = bundle.URLForResource("MyApp", withExtension: "momd")
       let model = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL!)!

       let psc = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: model)

       let privateContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
       privateContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc

       let documentsURL = CoreDataStack.applicationDocumentsDirectory()
       let storeURL = documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("MyApp.sqlite")

       let options = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true]

       var error: NSError? = nil
       let store: NSPersistentStore?
       do {
           store = try psc.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: storeURL, options: options)
       } catch let error1 as NSError {
           error = error1
           store = nil
       }

       if store == nil {
           print("Error adding persistent store: \(error)")
           abort()
       }

       return privateContext
   }

   class func applicationDocumentsDirectory() -> NSURL {
       let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
       let urls = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask) 
       return urls[0]
   }

}
```

I need to firstly confirm/clarify some points:

A) Is it legal/correct to create a full Core Data stack to use a context in a private queue the way I'm doing?

B) Would creating even a new `NSManagedObjectModel` from the same resource and same `.sqlite` file than the one used in the `AppDelegate` default Core Data stack cause problems?

About managing both contexts I have (the default in `AppDelegate`, let's call it `mainContext`, and the one I create in a private queue, let's call it `privateContext`):

- The `mainContext` is intended to show the `NSManagedObject` information throughout the app.
- The `privateContext` is intended to be used to call web services to get updated data, create the new `NSManagedObject` with the received information, and compare this new objects with the ones the app already have.

My questions regarding this are:

1. Should the `privateContext` be always used by calling `performBlock` or `performBlockAndWait`? Does that include all related operations, such s reading/inserting objects to the `privateContext`, and clearing/saving it?
2. The `mainContext` is supposed to be associated to the main queue/thread, right? So then all its related operations should be performed in main thread...
3. Having into account that `privateContext` has its own full Core Data stack... if I save its objects, would they be stored at the same `.sqlite` file than the ones when saving the `mainContext`? Or would such file be some way "duplicated"?
4. If `privateContext` should save data from its private queue, and `mainContext` should be used in main thread, would it cause any problem to fetch from the `mainContext` the data that was saved from the `privateContext`?

I need help to understand and correctly manage `Core Data` concurrency in my app, I'm making a mess with all this persistence staff and I'm occasionally finding errors in operations that seemed to work... thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing all this instead of just creating the private context as a child of the main context? Do you have a lot of data to process where you've seen issues with the 'standard' approach?

Comment: @Wain I update the managed objects I have in my main context by calling web services to get the new information. User doesn't edit those objects. And I'm not able to update the objects until I have received the new info from the services, created the new objects with such info, and compare with the objects I already had. Because I can be told to delete some of them, modify the attributes of some others, and/or insert new ones.

Comment: @Wain so, my idea was to use a completely separated and private Core Data stack (the one I describe in the question) to call the services, create the new received managed objects, and once having them in the private context, compare with the managed objects in the main context. Then perform the changes in the main context and save. Am I doing wrong?

Comment: It just seems you're doing more work than required. Have you looked at things like restkit?

Comment: @Wain I already implemented all the services calls and JSON responses parsing stuff without third-parties... would ResKit help me with the Core Data stuff?

Comment: It would likely help you with a lot of things, simplify your stack and replace all your parsing logic with a simple mapping spec. Your current approach, and the number of questions you have trying to solve problems with it, is very complicated, start simple and then go more complex of testing shows you have some issue.

Comment: @Wain you are right, in fact I just asked a new question regarding my data updates scenario (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32805731/best-approach-to-update-managed-objects-from-async-web-services-responses). The thing is, I have no much time right now to re-write a lot of things of the app, would learning RestKit take too much time? Could I only use it to simplify my Core Data related stuff, or would I have to also re-write all my services, data model and JSON parsing stuff? I'm afraid I can't do that at this point of the app development...

Comment: You would redo the services and remove the parsing. It would do all the parsing, mapping, updates and core data stack. Take a look at the examples, it's generally quick and easy.